# Binding state to Route Switch

Tags: reactjs

I am building a React app that fetches JSON data from an API call and feeds the response into an app state called menus [] as follows:

**App.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Menus from './components/menus';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    menus: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('api url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data)=> {
      this.setState({menus: data})
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <div>    
    <Menus menus={this.state.menus} />
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Im using the state in a simple component that contains a route switch as follows:

**Menus.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Menus = ({ menus }) => {
  return (
      <Router>
    <div>
      <center><h1>Lessons</h1></center>
      {menus.map((menu) => (

            <li><Link to="{{menu.lessonContent}}">{menu.lessonName}</Link></li> 

      ))}
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
  )
};
function Child() {
    // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
    // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
    let { id } = useParams();

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>ID: {id}</h3> //content should show up here
      </div>
    );
  }

export default Menus
```

Is there a way to bind a state element to the route so a different portion of the json response will be passed instead of a route? Can I use a key and somehow combine it with an element?

Here is what the link was originally:

```
<li><Link to="/route">{menu.lessonName}</Link></li>
```

and here is what I need it to be:

```
<li><Link to="{{menu.lessonContent}}">{menu.lessonName}</Link></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying achieve, I think your `Menus` component should look more like this:

**Menus.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const Menus = ({ menus }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>Lessons</h1>
        </center>
        {menus.map(menu => (
          <li key={menu.id}>
            <Link to={`/${menu.id}`}>{menu.lessonName}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
        <Switch>
          {menus.map(menu => (
            <Route
              key={menu.id}
              path="/:id"
              children={<Child content={menu.content} />}
            />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
function Child({ content }) {
  let { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menus;
```

Here are some of the things I fixed here:

1. On your example you were passing a string instead of an object key to the `to` prop: `to="{{menu.lessonContent}}"` instead of `to={menu.lessonContent}`
2. I'm mapping over `menus` in order to dynamically create the `Route` components and their corresponding paths.
3. I'm passing `menu.content` as a prop to the `Child` component.
4. I added [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to every rendered element which is a result of iteration.